# ros-hydro-desktop-full installs gazebo-current instead of gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [gazebosim wiki](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Install/Gazebo_and_ROS), version 1.9.x of gazebo should be installed when ros hydro is installed but for reasons unknown I'm getting gazebo-current (i.e. version 2.x.y) installed. Any idea why?

I'm entering:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

and the output is:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
gazebo-current ...
```

I've also had gazebo-current install earlier but have since removed it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101976/ros-hydro-desktop-full-installs-gazebo-current-instead-of-gazebo/) by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 438 on 2013-11-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It boils down to the fact that there are two debian repositories (ROS and OSRF) offering different versions of gazebo_ros_pkgs and gazebo / gazebo-current.

ROS Repository:

- provides gazebo 1.9.x and gazebo_ros_pkgs 2.3.x for hydro as ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs.

OSRF Repository (this was created for DRCSim and for testing gazebo_ros_pkgs against newer versions of gazebo):

- provides gazebo 1.9 and gazebo-current 2.1
- provides gazebo_ros_pkgs 2.4.x for hydro as ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs that depends on gazebo-current 2.1.

To make sure you do not end up installing the version of ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs 2.4.x that uses gazebo-current, remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/osrf*.list` or comment out its content:

```
# deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu [quantal/precise/...] main
```

Then remove gazebo-ros-pkgs and gazebo, update and reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove gazebo-current ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-pkgs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-[...]
```

**Note** that we are in the process of renaming ros-hydro-gazebo-pkgs 2.4.x in OSRF repo to ros-hydro-gazebo-pkgs-current to avoid confusions.

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4